# Missing rows of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

When I run this code, there won't be any rows in the new data frame. How can I get all the rows from that "reconstruct" data frame into the new data frame? Thanks in advance!

```
newdata <- reconstruct %>%
  select(c("unit", "K1", "K2")) %>%
  filter("unit" == 12) %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "question",
               values_to = "answer",
               cols = -unit) %>%
  group_by(question) %>%
  summarise( 
    n=n(),
    mean=mean(answer),
    sd=sd(answer))
```

This is the data I used:

```
structure(list(unit = c(4, 3, 6, 1, 12), K1 = c(6, 7, 5, 6, 6
), K2 = c(5, 6, 5, 5, 6), K3 = c(5, 6, 7, 6, 6), K4 = c(5, 7, 
                                                        5, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                     "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your third line is not correct i.e. it should be `filter(unit == 12)` (quoting the column name would do a literal comparison between "unit" string and 12

Comment: Awesome akrun thanks!